# Fortran 90 producing the incorrect answer, produces 0 when the answer should be 1. Am I overlooking anything?

Tags: math, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

Here is the Fortran 90 code I have written. It is a function that I am using in a larger code but I am getting incorrect results.

I know mathematically the answer should be 1 (or close to 1 due to computation) but my answer result is 0.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there something that I do not know?

Here is the my code saved as *test.f90* that I am compiling and running on windows gfortran:

```
program main
    implicit none

    real*8 :: y, t

    t = 0.0
    y = (1/3)*exp(5*t) + (2/3)*exp(-t) + t*t*exp(2*t)

    print*, 'y= ', y

end program main
```

Comment: Good work producing a small reproducible test code. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

fortran considers 1/3 and 2/3 to be equal to zero. you should add a point to your numbers:

```
program main
implicit none

real*8 :: y, t

t = 0.0
y = (1./3.)*exp(5*t) + (2./3.)*exp(-t) + t*t*exp(2*t)

print*, 'y= ', y
```

Comment: This answer really should be expanded - why is `1/3` and `2/3` equal to 0, and why do the decimals help? Also, there are clearly duplicates to point to...

Comment: Furthermore, `2./3.` are typically single-precision reals, which means the result will be inaccurate compared to `2._dp/3._dp`, where `dp` is the relevant kind. Using `*8*` is not recommended.

Comment: have a look at this article: http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~hile/fortran/fort3.htm#double